# Bash search command that checks preceeding characters

Tags: bash, unix, grep

Not sure if the title is worded correctly, but I am looking for a bash command that checks the characters before the search term.  For example, if I have a file (lines.txt) that contains a list of words:

```
stackoverflow
stack overflow
stack over flow
```

I need the command that will search for the word `over`, but exclude any results that have `stack` immediately before it.  so in the above example only the last two lines will hit.

I have `grep -i 'over' lines.txt | grep -v 'stackover"`, but is there a better way/option of writing this?  I've tinkered with a few other options (`-E` and `-P`) and have been reading up on negative lookaheads/behinds, but can't get the NOT part working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a negative look-behind should help:

```
grep -P '(?<!stack)over'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a word boundary will do the trick:

```
grep '\<over'
```